# Python unresolved reference import MIMEMultipart

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am writing some code in Pycharm to send my Selenium test result report in an email with an attachment.

In my import statement I am getting the error:

```
unresolved reference MIMEMultipart
unresolved reference MIMEText
unresolved reference MIMEBase
```

My import statement is written like this:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
```

Do I need to install any packages?

My full code snippet is:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase

class Email(BasePage):


    def send_email(self):
        import smtplib


        from email import encoders

        fromaddr = "YOUR EMAIL"
        toaddr = "EMAIL ADDRESS YOU SEND TO"

        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE EMAIL"

        body = "TEXT YOU WANT TO SEND"

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = "NAME OF THE FILE WITH ITS EXTENSION"
        attachment = open("PATH OF THE FILE", "rb")

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

        msg.attach(part)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(fromaddr, "YOUR PASSWORD")
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
        server.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email package was refactored at some point and the Mime support is now in the `email.mime` package.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html

Comment: That's it, there is no `MIMEMultipart` package under `email`; only `email.mime.multipart` exists. The OP could just drop the package names as `from email import MIMEMultipart` does work.

Comment: I have added these import statements now.  from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

Comment: For the following import statement from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart I get the error No module named mime.multipart

Answer (score 10):

With python 3.6:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
```